# How to make 2 sections side by side on Elementor Pro Page Builder?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to make 2 sections side by side on Elementor Pro Page Builder

I'm trying to make two sections side by side [in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWOv0.jpg) elementor page builder. What I have done so far Created a section (section 1) and added CSS

```
 selector {
        max-width: 50%;
```

Duplicated this and it's under the first section, I want to be side by side.

```
selector {
max-width:50%;
display:flex;
float:right:
}
```

But it's not working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

look into using flex.  Also, try not to use float unless you absolutely have to. It doesn't scale well

```css
body, html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#left,#right{
width:50%;
height:100vh;
background-color:blue;
}

#right{
background-color:red;
}

#container{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id ="left"></div>
  <div id ="right"></div>
 </div>
```

*emphasized text*